# 1980s fantasy film with bat-like creatures that wrapped their prey in their wings?

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know the title of a 1980s fantasy film which had creepy black creatures with bat like wings which they wrapped wound their victims and then digested them, and all that was left was a pile of bones and goo.

I thought it might be *Dragonslayer* but seems a bit unusual for Disney.

Answer (score 20):

I suspect that you are talking about the 'Bat Creatures' from '[The Beastmaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beastmaster_%28film%29)' (1982) which were creatures that (for religious reasons relating to his Eagle) allied to the hero and engaged in such behavior.

Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SegQXGEGKw) to a Youtube video of one feeding.
[image: One with it's arms open]
[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly what the question refers to. The end of this sequence is a pile of bones falling to the ground from under the wings.

Comment: I loved how they had these intriguing monsters without any sort of explanation, just threw them into the story. Arguably one of the most unpleasant (in terms of their mode of killing) monsters in fiction, no idea what might have inspired this species -- spiders of course sort of eat this way and we saw a very gross scene like this in The Fly (Cronenberg version.)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly Stephen King's [Graveyard Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_Shift_(1990_film)) (loosely) based on a short story of the same name. Trying to find an image...

[image]

This doesn't show it doing the actual behavior, but I remember it distinctly. Technically not the 1980s though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the "Dead Tree" scene from "Beastmaster".  The Beastmaster walks up to a tree of these bat-things catches a random stranger and digest him before giving the BM a magic-brass-ring.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beastmaster_%28film%29

A picture of one of them is on this page.
http://www.heropress.net/2011/10/more-beastmaster-gaming-goodness.html

Answer (score -3):

I believe you mean [Jeepers Creepers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_%282001_film%29). The monster in that film is described as follows:

> the true nature of their pursuer: it is an ancient creature, known as "The Creeper", which hunts every twenty-third spring for twenty-three days to feast on human body parts and organs, which then become a part of its own body. She also tells them that it seeks out its victims through fear, and, by smelling the fear from Trish and Darry, it has found something it likes, but she does not know what.