# Dr Who episode with bat like creatures

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I was just talking with a friend about an old Dr Who episode from the late 70s or early 80s where there were some kind of humanoid bat like alien with leathery wings that they used like a cloak to envelop people and dissolve them.

We were talking about it because it was an episode that scared the bejezus out of me when I was a little kid. Does anyone know what episode this was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry my mistake - it wasn't Dr Who it was the film "The Beastmaster" in my memory this was Dr Who but I was only about 7 or something...

[1980s fantasy film with bat-like creatures that wrapped their prey in their wings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/1980s-fantasy-film-with-bat-like-creatures-that-wrapped-their-prey-in-their-wing)

Apologies for the wild goose chase ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Could you be referring to Kronos the Chronovore from The Time Monster.<sup>1</sup>

He is a bird like being who devours people.

[image]

---

**Option 2**

Magnus from the Talons of Weng Chiang<sup>2</sup>wears a cloak and devours people, doesn't really fit the bat like tendencies though

[image]

---

**Option 3**

The State of Decay<sup>3</sup> contains giant space vampires who's minions wear cloaks and have limited vampiric abilities

[image]

<sup>1. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Monster</sup>
<sup>2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Talons_of_Weng-Chiang</sup>
<sup>3. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Decay</sup>

Comment: No, it's not that, they had leathery bat like wings. I seem to remember the story involved them being the inspiration for the vampires in human culture. It is possible that it wasn't Dr Who at all...

Comment: @ChrisB updated with more options

Comment: Or tetraps maybe?